# Using Python and elasticsearch, how can I loop through the returned JSON object?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

My code is as follows:

```
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

resp = es.search(index="mynewcontacts", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
    response = json.dumps(resp)
    data = json.loads(response)
    #print data["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["email"]
    for row in data:
    print row["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["email"]
    return "OK"
```

which produces this truncated (for convenience) JSON:

```
{"timed_out": false, "took": 1, "_shards": {"successful": 5, "total": 5, "failed": 0}, "hits": {"max_score": 1.0, "total": 7, "hits": [{"_index": "mynewcontacts", "_type": "contact", "_score": 1.0, 
"_source": {"email": "sharon.zhuo@xxxxx.com.cn", "position": "Sr.Researcher", "last": "Zhuo", "first": "Sharon", "company": "Tabridge Executive Search"}, "_id": "AVYmLMlKJVSAh7zyC0xf"},
{"_index": "mynewcontacts", "_type": "contact", "_score": 1.0, "_source": {"email": "andrew.springthorpe@xxxxx.gr.jp", "position": "Vice President", "last": "Springthorpe", "first": "Andrew", "company": "SBC Group"}, "_id": "AVYmLMlRJVSAh7zyC0xg"}, {"_index": "mynewcontacts", "_type": "contact", "_score": 1.0, "_source": {"email": "mjbxxx@xxx.com", "position": "Financial Advisor", "last": "Bell", "first": "Margaret Jacqueline", "company": "Streamline"}, "_id": "AVYmLMlXJVSAh7zyC0xh"}, {"_index": "mynewcontacts", "_type": "contact", "_score": 1.0, "_source": {"email": "kokaixxx@xxxx.com", "position": "Technical Solutions Manager MMS North Asia", "last": "Okai", "first": "Kensuke", "company": "Criteo"}, "_id": "AVYmLMlfJVSAh7zyC0xi"}, {"_index": "mynewcontacts", "_type": "contact", "_score": 1.0, "_source": {"email": "mizuxxxxto@zszs.com", "position": "Sr. Strategic Account Executive", "last": "Kato", "first": "Mizuto", "company": "Twitter"}, "_id": "AVYmLMlkJVSAh7zyC0xj"}, {"_index": "mynewcontacts", "_type": "contact", "_score": 1.0, "_source": {"email": "abc@example.com", "position": "Design Manager", "last": "Okada", "first": "Kengo", "company": "ON Semiconductor"}, "_id": "AVYmLMlpJVSAh7zyC0xk"}, {"_index": "mynewcontacts", "_type": "contact", "_score": 1.0, "_source": {"email": "007@example.com", "position": "Legal Counsel", "last": "Lei", "first": "Yangzi (Karen)", "company": "Samsung China Semiconductor"}, "_id": "AVYmLMkUJVSAh7zyC0xe"}]}}
```

When I try:

```
print data["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["email"]
```

it prints the first email fine but when I attempt the loop with

```
for row in data:
    print row["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["email"]
```

I receive an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Please can somebody suggest how I can iterate through the items correctly? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing is looping through keys of the dictionary.  To print each email in the response you'd do this:

```
for row in data["hits"]["hits"]:
    print row["_source"]["email"]
```

Also converting to json isn't necessary.  This should accomplish what you're looking to do:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

resp = es.search(index="mynewcontacts", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
for row in resp["hits"]["hits"]:
    print row["_source"]["email"]
return "OK"
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but looks like you might not be starting the for loop based on the correct json item.  Try:

```
for row in data['hits']['hits']:
    # Rest of loop here.
```

Comment: In your original code you had retrieved a dictionary key too deep int the json data.

Answer (score 1):

Your retrieved response `data` is a Python dictionary - if you make a  `for` loop over it, it will yield the dictionary keys - in this case, teh strigns `timed_out`, `took`, `shards`, etc...

Aparently yu want to iterate over teh list provided in the position `data["_shards"]["hits"]["hits"]`  in your response data. That is a list.

So, just do

```
for row in data["_shards"]["hits"]["hits"]:
    print(row["_source"]["email"])
```